Folder Shortcut Infotips don't Display Target Folder Info
How display a folder shortcut's infotip popup with the same items as the original folder's infotip? I'm aware of how to add properties to shortcut infotips via Regedit, but that approach only allows seven properties (Title, Subject, Author, Keywords, Comment, Size, Link.TargetParsingPath) and that's not even half of the original folder's properties.
